# python open file in memory , run replace and then save

Tags: python, regex, replace

Trying to do the below:

1. Open a file in memory
2. Read it line by line
3. Search multiple patterns in the line
4. IF match is found replace it by a random hash generated by a function.

I see my replace is not working and also how do i save the edited file without creating a new one.

This is my code.

```
with open('temp', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        firstPattern = re.search(r'email=(.*?)"', line)
        secondPattern = re.search(r'"emailTo":"(.*?)"', line)
        thirdPattern = re.search(r'pid="(.*?)"', line)

        if firstPattern:
            random_hash = hash_generator()
            temp_var = firstPattern.group(1)
            if temp_var in pattern_dict:
                line.replace(str(temp_var), str(random_hash))
            else:
                pattern_dict[firstPattern.group(1)] = random_hash
        elif secondPattern:
            random_hash = hash_generator()
        temp_var = secondPattern.group(1)
            if temp_var in pattern_dict:
                line.replace(str(temp_var), str(random_hash))
            else:
                pattern_dict[secondPattern.group(1)] = random_hash
        elif thirdPattern:
            random_hash = hash_generator()
        temp_var = thirdPattern.group(1)
            if temp_var in pattern_dict:
                line.replace(str(temp_var), str(random_hash))
            else:
                pattern_dict[thirdPattern.group(1)] = random_hash
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The file is opened in 'r' mode, which means you cannot write to it under the with. Since you already have the modified data in memory, try closing the file in 'r' mode and open a 'w' mode for writing.

Comment: I don't see my replace as working . It does not replace the patterns with the random hash.

Comment: replace will not modify the line, but returns a COPY of the line with old value replaced by value. So if you use line = line.replace( old, new ), it will work.